# Captcha module configuration

Tags: 7

I am using the CAPTCHA module on my user registration form. I need to alter the error message from *What code is in the image? field is required.* to *My custom text*.

Is there any hook to alter the error message, or some other way to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the [String Overrides](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module, search for the string, and replace it with your custom one.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [String Overrides](https://www.drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module.

> Provides a quick and easy way to replace any text on the site.
>
> **Features**
>
> Easily replace anything that's passed through t() Locale support,
>   allowing you to override strings in any language Ability to
>   import/export *.po files, for easy migration from the Locale module
>   Note that this is not a replacement to Locale as having thousands of
>   overrides can cause more pain then benefit. Use this only if you need
>   a few easy text changes.